# Elementary bound for the reciprocal of the Riemann zeta function for real $s \ge 2$

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, analytic-number-theory

I was playing around with $\zeta(s)^{-1}$ and after plugging in some values for $s$, it seems like we have
$$\zeta(s)^{-1} = 1 - \epsilon(s)$$
for $\epsilon(s) < 2^{-s}$ where $s \in [2,\infty)$? To rephrase the question: for every real $s \ge 2$, can we show that $\zeta(s)^{-1} > 1 - 2^{-s}$? For now, using the well-known formula:
$$\zeta(s)^{-1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$$
I was able to get a bound like $\zeta(s)^{-1} > 1 - 3\cdot 2^{-s}$ for every $s \in [2,\infty)$ by the following steps:
$$\frac{1 - \zeta(s)^{-1}}{2^{-s}} = \sum_{n \ge 2}\frac{-\mu(n)}{(n/2)^{s}} \leq \sum_{n \ge 2}\frac{1}{(n/2)^{2}} = 4(\zeta(2) - 1) < 3.$$
I wonder if anyone could show me a way to get rid of the $3$ or find a $s \in [2,\infty)$ such that $\zeta(s)^{-2} \leq 1 - 2^{-s}$?

Comment: $1/\zeta(2)=6/\pi^2<.61 <3/4=1-1/4$ so the inequality is not true at $2$; since in $1/\zeta$ you start with $1-2^{-s}-3^{-s}..$ I kind of doubt it is true anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality you are aiming for fails for all $s>1$, because
$$(1-2^{-s})^{-1}=1+2^{-s}+4^{-s}+8^{-s}+\ldots <1+2^{-s}+3^{-s}+4^{-s}+\ldots =\zeta(s)\,.$$